# why hash partitioning in oracle introduced? what is the advantage

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hash, partitioning

I undergone various websites about hash partitioning in oracle but I am unable to understand the advantage of it.
I came to know that even sometimes by using range partition the data can be distributed uneven.
So we are going for Hash Partitioning.

So anyone please explain me what is hash partitioning,necessity of hash partitioning?

why we are going for Hash partitioning?

why we are using 2 power n tablespaces in creating hash partitioning

what happens exactly when we do hash partitioning?

Please can anyone explain me in detail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, partitioning brings about many things for you.  forget about partition elimination 
for a moment:

- instead of having a 100 gig tablespace to backup, you have 100, 1 gig tablespaces. 
  (each tablespace spends less time in backup mode, reduces the amount of potential extra 
  redo, reduces the amount of manual recovery you need to do if the instance failes during 
  backup).  same with restores.
- instead of having an index on a 100 gig table, you have say 100 indexes on 1 gig 
  tables.  You can rebuild each one fast.... (and online with minimal overhead).
  rebuilding a single index on a 100 gig table -- that would take maybe 100 times longer 
  then each individual rebuild (true parallel query might reduce that).
- you can analyze each partition quickly, instead of running an analyze on a 100 gig 
  table.
- you can reorg each partition independent of any other partition
- you can easily redistribute the load over many disks, you now have evenly distributed 
  the data into 100 1 gig partitions, move them at will.  If you did this manually -- you 
  would have a heck of a time moving the stuff around.
- and so on (every single admin option you do to a partition applies to a hash 
  partition).
- as a bonus, you no longer have to load this data into this file in direct path mode, 
  that data into that file and so on.  Just let the software do that work for you.  True, 
  us humans can do lots of stuff -- but -- when the software can do it for me....  maybe 
  even better then I can... its worth a shot.

Now, lets re-introduce partition elimination.  Say you are an OLTP system.  You would 
pick a PARTITION key that is used in most all queries (say a CUSTOMER_ID, an ORDER_ID, 
something).  It is very hard to range partition on that (almost impossible on something 
like an ORDER_ID) but very trivial to hash partition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what u meant.Basically I need what happens internally when we create hash partitioning how it distributes the data.

Comment: On nowadays SAN (Storage Area Network) most of your points regarding backup or disk load are not valid in my opinion. Rebuild an index makes only sense for a global index but there it makes no difference. A partitionized index is only usefull when you know the partition where your data is stored which is not the case for HASH values, by default. Otherwise Oracle has to scan (in your example) 100 index partitions which is almost equal to 100 individual indexes. This slows down your queries significantly.